# When i click on map its get crashed at the initial time in iOS5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

```
for (int i = 0; i< [delarsInfoArray count] ; i++)
{
    NSString *lattitudeValue;
    NSString *longitudeValue;
    if ([[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]count]>1) {
        lattitudeValue = [[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LATITUDE"]objectAtIndex:1];
        longitudeValue = [[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LONGITUDE"]objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        lattitudeValue = @"";
        longitudeValue = @"";
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pinLocation;
    if(([lattitudeValue floatValue] != 0) && ([longitudeValue floatValue] != 0) ) {
        mapRegion.center.latitude = [lattitudeValue floatValue];
        mapRegion.center.longitude = [longitudeValue floatValue];
        if(pinLocation.latitude !=0 && pinLocation.longitude !=0) {
            myAnnotation1 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
            if ([[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i] count] == 0) {

                myAnnotation1.title  = @"";
                myAnnotation1.subtitle = @"";
            }
            else
            {
                // NSLog(@"====== delears array is===%@",delarsInfoArray);
                NSLog(@"===== delears array count is %d",[delarsInfoArray count]);

                if ([[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Address"]objectAtIndex:2] !=nil)
                {
                    myAnnotation1.title = [[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Address"]objectAtIndex:2];
                }
                if ([[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"City"]objectAtIndex:3]!= nil) {
                    myAnnotation1.subtitle = [[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"City"]objectAtIndex:3];
                }

                NSLog(@"%@",[[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"City"]objectAtIndex:3]);
            }

            [dealerMapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];
            [dealerMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
            myAnnotation1.coordinate = mapRegion.center;
            [myAnnotation1 release];
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is written in the viewWillAppear.After loading the map in to the view,when i clicked on the map.app gets crashed.How can solve this crash?

Comment: dealerMapView is attached via (weak) IBoutlet or it is created in ur code??

Comment: wt is error message in console ?

Comment: @samfisher : IBOutlet MKMapView *dealerMapView; i attached through xib

Comment: @iPatel -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x430cd8
  Im getting this message on console

Comment: Personally, I'd also be inclined to suggest a simple structure of `delarsInfoArray`, but that's a broader conversation. If you consider each object at `[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]`, it would appear that each of those objects is an array of single entry dictionaries, which is unnecessarily complicated, inefficient, and fragile. I would have just made each of those objects a dictionary. But I recognize that this drags you into reevaluating the code that built `delarsInfoArray`, which you might be reticent to contemplate.

Comment: I'd also discourage you from setting the region of the map from within this loop. Let's say you have a 10 annotations on your map. Why set the region for those first nine annotations? I'd suggest you just keep track of the last annotation and set the map's center on the basis of that (or define a region that covers the full set of annotations). But you definitely don't need to change the region 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues here, but the one that leaps out to the top of the list are the lines that read:

```
if ([[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Address"]objectAtIndex:2] !=nil)
    ...
```

and

```
if ([[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"City"]objectAtIndex:3]!= nil) {
    ...
```

The problem is that `objectAtIndex` of a `valueForKey` of an array will *never* be `nil`. You can't store a `nil` in an array, so what `valueForKey` does, if it doesn't find a value, is it uses a `NSNull` object, `[NSNull null]`. That designates that there was no value found, but uses `NSNull` (which can be added to the array) instead of `nil` (which can't).

The problem is likely that there is some subsequent code (for example, the code that tries to figure out the size of the callout bubble) which tries to get the length of the string, but since you stored a `NSNull`, it's trying to call the `length` method and it's failing.

You could fix this a number of ways, such as:

```
if ([[[delarsInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Address"]objectAtIndex:2] != [NSNull null])
    ...
```